# How many questions and answers did you promise to post per week when you committed to a proposal, and for how long?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, area-51, commitment-phase

Can you answer the question in the title without looking it up?

I bet you can't and this makes the whole "contract" that you have to sign with your real name (lol) completely pointless.

Can we please remove the strict number "obligations" that anyways no-one is going to obey to? If someone likes the site they'll use it otherwise they won't. Making them promise that they'll post a certain number of questions or answers won't help anything.

I think the text should be changed to something like this:

> By committing to this website you
>   promise that you will try it out
>   during the beta phase.

This is a much more realistic promise. And please no more "real name" signing. Just an old fashioned "I accept" button.

Comment: Sue me! Ha ha ha ha ha! +1

Comment: I would much rather the strict number be easier to find during closed beta.

Comment: It is also totally pointless. You don't even know the level of questions going to be asked.

Answer (score 2):

We simplified it a bit last week.  The text now reads:

> I commit to participate actively in Home Improvement for at least three months, especially 
>   during the private beta, and to ask or answer at least ten questions.

So you committed to asking / answering 10 questions.

Comment: Does asking 5 and answering 5 count?

Comment: @Tim: The way I read it, yes.

Comment: @Tim Yes, any 10 posts (questions or answers)